# Powershell output data from import-csv in for each loop

Tags: database, powershell, csv

I am having some difficulties with writing off CSV lines in the body of an automated e-mail.
I want to do this:

I have the import-csv.
Which contains several rows separated by comma's. There are 10 row values per row (each value separated by comma).
In each loop in the for each clause I want to write off these 10 values. And then it should go to the next line and go through the 10 values again until it has written off all the rows in the body of the e-mail.

As you can see below I am still figuring out how to do this. The shell debugger is not giving me any information.

```js
$lines = import-csv $RESULT
#${lines}
If ($lines -ne $null ) 
{
 foreach ($line in $lines) 
 { 
 $QUERY = $line.v1
 $DB_NAME = $line.v2
 $AGENT_ID = $line.v3
 
 $body = 
 "QUERY    :" + $QUERY + "`n" + 
 "DB_NAME   :" + $DB_NAME + "`n" +
 "AGENT_ID   :" + $AGENT_ID + "`n"
# "AUTHID    :" +  $lines[4] + "`n" +
# "ELAPSED_TIME_MIN :" +  $lines[5] + "`n" +
# "APPL_NAME    :" +  $lines[6] + "`n" +
# "APPL_STATUS   :" +  $lines[7] + "`n" +
# "SNAPSHOT_TIMESTAMP :" +  $lines[9] + "`n" +
# "CLIENT_PID   :" +  $lines[10] + "`n" +
# "CLIENT_NNAME   :" +  $lines[11] + "`r`n"
 
 #"Email Body set"
 #"${body}"
 }

 $subject = "WARNING - LONG RUNNING QUERIES on Database *****"
 $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
 $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $MAILTO, $subject, $body)

sleep 10
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is exactly, but I guess one thing that's wrong is the use of `$lines` in the `$body = ` statement. You should use the loop variable `$line` here.

Comment: I might be easier to use the `-Header` parameter of `import-csv` and do something along the lines of: `$body = $lines | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String`.

Comment: Yes that is correct but that is just an example of the code. My question is how do I get the data from the array and loop through the whole CSV in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my second comment the code could look something like:

```
$header = @("Query","Database","Agent ID","Authentication ID",
    "Elapsed time (min)","Application Name","Snapshot Timestamp",
    "Client PID", "Client Name")
$lines = import-csv $RESULT -Header $header 
$body = $lines | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width ([Int32]::MaxValue)
$subject = "WARNING - LONG RUNNING QUERIES on Database *****"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $MAILTO, $subject, $body)
```

I hope this helps. So the tric is to use as much of PowerShell's power as you can.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not giving the desired output in the e-mail I was looking for. Please see below output in the e-mail : http://i.imgur.com/9cgWlD9.png

Comment: I need the output ordered on the left side instead of columns like it is right now. This way I can store the biggest value the QUERY text without messing up the format of the other columns. I tried getting this done with an array but somehow it is not working.